# Is it bad to not remove elements from HTML that aren't visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, slideshow

I've made a slideshow using JQuery which at the moment just uses `append()` to add an `<img>` to a container that was previously defined. The slideshow automatically rotates through, returning back the the start after the final slide and continuing infinitely.

At the moment, I don't remove the previous image in the container at all. I haven't noticed anything change in terms of performance or my memory filling up - a behaviour that I'm used to in Flash if I were to continue adding elements without removing old ones.

Is it necessary to remove the old images, or are these never going to cause performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of this might be browser-dependent, but in general I would say that yes it is indeed "bad" not to clean up your old elements.  Whether or not an element is visible, it is still adding a node to the structure of the DOM, and you cannot add to the DOM infinitely.

Unless perhaps the browser implements some sort of intelligent pruning algorithm that swaps out unused/non-visible portions of the DOM, but I've never heard of such a thing being done in practice.

Comment: Your latter comment likely wouldn't apply, because the previous slide wouldn't be considered non-visible by the browser, it simply has a new element placed over it. Could you elaborate more on your first point about not being able to add to the DOM infinitely?

Comment: @Marty Wallace - Sure.  When you call `append()` to add an `<img>` element to some existing container, this creates a new `Node` for that element and adds it as a child of the container's `Node` in the DOM (Document-Object-Model).  The DOM is just a data-structure that represents the current state of the webpage/document.  So in essence, every time you `append()` something, this data structure gets slightly bigger, and it can only grow so large before the browser runs out of memory.

Comment: Ah, so my concern should be around the browsers memory. That makes sense; +1.

Comment: @Marty Wallace - Yes.  Though in practice it will probably take a very long time/large number of `<img>` elements to cause a serious issue.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, it will affect performance over time, the more photos added, the more the performance will suffer, but if at all possible, test it out, add as many as you can, but if there is not a whole lot going on in your site, you may not see any performance issues. if you don't see any issues, don't worry about it. like i said, try it out.

Comment: At the moment I'm not not all that concerned about the performance. I mean, people aren't going to have this page up for 15 hours waiting for it to get slow, and visually there's nothing wrong either. It's more a question derived from my curiosity. Adding a tonne of images really quickly might be a good strategy though, if I don't get a solid answer I'll give that a whirl :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't adding  `$(div).innerHTML=''` before appending the image clear everything off in the div?

Comment: This would void the current transition I have happening, which is the new image fading in over the top of the previously added image, making it look real nice.

Comment: oops you didn't mention that ! :P

Answer (score 0):

The browser caches any images that are loaded.  Each image does consume memory but removing the images won't affect the cache.  If the cache starts to become a problem, the browser will start freeing up memory.  Each browser does this differently and some do it better than others.  Any image that is not visible in the viewable space of the current page is fair game.  If an image on the current page is thrown out and subsequently made visible in the viewable area of the page it is reloaded.

In summary, removing the old images won't affect performance.

Comment: So more accurately you mean to say that there's no advantage in removing elements that have been added to the page?

Comment: That's not true for all elements.  There's very little overhead to the img container itself.  That's why I say there's no real advantage in this case.  Removing elements with more overhead such as input, select, textarea, etc. can make a difference (but only if you're removing large quantities of them).